# Why is the expected value for ourcomes of equal probabilities different per outcome?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I am confused with grasping the expected value definition which is to multiply each possible outcome by its probability and add the products.

For example if we would want to find the expected value for the outcome of a roll of a fair dice, based on this definition and taking into account that the possible outcomes are $1,2,3,4,5,6$ each with probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ the expected value $E$ would be:

$E = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 3 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 4 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 5 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 6 \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{21}{6} = 3.5$

What is confusing to me is that if I check each part of that formula I see for example $1 \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$ which is the expected value for $1$ as an outcome and $2 \cdot \frac{1}{6}= \frac{1}{3}$ which is the expected value for $2$ as an outcome but the latter is larger than the former while I would think that both cases should have the same value since they have the exact same possibility.

So I don't understand how we are using a formula that the parts are giving different weights for occurences that have the exact same probability to occur.

Could someone please help me understand the concept? (if possible in a non rigorous but intuitive explanation)

Comment: Throwing a 6 is six times as valuable than throwing a 1. We are calculating the expected {**value** of the die}.

Comment: The expected value is an average of all of the outcomes. It doesn't make sense to talk about the expected value of an outcome. The fact that each value has an equal likelihood of occurring is captured by the fact that each value has a probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ of occurring.

Comment: What would be the expected value be if all outcomes had the same value?  What would be the point?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: I think I am misunderstanding something then. Is the statement that $6$ is more valuable than $1$ related to gamble? In what sense it is more valuable? I guess my confusion is what we mean by value here

Comment: @JohnDouma: each value has the same probability but the weight of each probability is not the same. This part is confusing to me.

Comment: I just posted what I hope is a clarification below.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: If all the outcomes had the same value then that would mean there is actually only one outcome, right?

Comment: The value of an outcome is *not* the weight of its probability.  It is a measure assigned for, well, some reason.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: I consider it as weight since the probability is multiplied by it

Comment: There in lies your problem - terminology.  Expected value is defined as the weighted mean of the values; where the probability is the weight given to each value.

Comment: @GrahamKemp:ah, so I have it reversed in my mind? And how come not "weight average"? Is "weight average" $\equiv$ "weight mean"?

Comment: (Arithmetic) Mean is one type of average.  Others include Mode, Median, Geometric Mean, ...

Comment: @GrahamKemp: ah, I always thought average is $\frac{total\_sum}{total\_occurences}$ while mean is the middle value of the **sorted** instances and hence completely different things. E.g. $[1,2,3,4,5]$ average = $\frac{15}{5} = 3$ and mean = $3$. For $[1,2,3,4,5,6]$ mean would be $\frac{3 + 4}{2}$. Does that mean that even so mean is just another form of averaging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value tells us the average value we should get if we ran an experiment many times. Let's illustrate this by running two experiments with a six sided die.

In the first experiment we toss a six sided die and record the value. The outcomes are $1$ through $6$ and each has a probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ and we get the expected value of $3.5$ that you computed. This value tells us the average we should get if we ran that experiment many times. In other words, we record each value rolled, sum up the values and divide by the number of times we ran the experiment.

To address your question, suppose instead we flipped the die and counted the number of times the number $4$ was rolled. The outcomes of this experiment are $0$ and $1$ because on one roll of a die we can get either zero $4$s or one $4$. The probability of getting $1$ is $\frac{1}{6}$ and the probability of getting $0$ is $\frac{5}{6}$. Therefore, the expected value is $$\frac{5}{6}(0)+\frac{1}{6}(1)=\frac{1}{6}$$

This means if we run the experiment many times and record a $1$ every time we roll a $4$ and a $0$ every time we don't we expect an average of $\frac{1}{6}$. Notice that we would get the same value if we considered how many times we rolled each of the individual values of $1$ through $6$.

Comment: 1) so "expected value" $\equiv$ "average value"? How come is it not named "average" then?
2) If we roll the dice multiple times and record which side appeared, in the end if we sum the dots on the side that appeared and divide we get $3.5$ which I think does not mean that we got the side with $3$ on average but something else? So what is the meaning of $3.5$ if the only thing relevant to a dice is just which side comes up? I am sorry if this sounds trivial, somehow it is confusing to me

Comment: I am not an expert on the history of naming in mathematics but what makes this not an average in the traditional sense is that it is non-deterministic. If you run a hundred trials today you may get an average of $3.2$. Tomorrow you may get an average of $3.9$. Conceptually and computationally it is an average.

Comment: Also, there are other types of average - mean, mode, medium.  Expectation is the mean value.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: I thought average and mean are completely different things

Comment: So does $3.5$ means we get the side $3$ or $4$ in the long run?

Comment: No. It is the average value from running the experiment many times. You should run this yourself. Get a six-sided die and roll it twenty times and record the outcome. Then change the six to a fifty and run it again. Notice that the average goes higher. As far as how frequently a number comes up the second experiment above should show you there is no one value that it preferred over another. Each value has an equal likelihood of occurring.

Comment: One my assumptions was that the number on each side of the dice does not have any kind of value so that we add and get some information based on the total sum. I suppose the dice is just a way to simulate uniformly that some outcome that has value $[1,6]$ can occur, even by mapping the number on the side with some other value. I am sorry, I just cant figure out how to properly express the part that is still confusing to me when we use the term "value"

Comment: A universal principle that is true in science and mathematics is that definitions are precise. This means you cannot superimpose your understanding of an English word onto it and demand that a mathematical definition must conform to it. In this case, expected value does not mean the value we expect to come up next nor the number to bet on in a game of chance. Each of the numbers is equally likely to occur. If you change the numbers printed on the die you will get a different expected value but each number will still be equally likely to occur.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and rolled a dice $20$ times and recorded the outcomes: $[1,4,6,1,6,2,3,3,5,2,3,6,1,3,4,3,4,3,1,2]$ which gives as expected value $3.15$. It seems to me that this value is an indication of how fair the dice is since if it is fair the running average has to be somewhere in the middle. Have I got that right? Is there anything else that this value gives us as information? You are absolutely right in your previous comment. I am trying to untangle the meaning of "value" in english to what we mean in this particular case by value

Comment: @Jim As you can see the value was close to $3.5$ but not exact. Now, choose different numbers. On a piece of paper, every time you roll $1$, call it something else like 17.2. Do the same for each of the numbers on the die. Calculate their average and re-run the experiment. You should get a value close to your computed average.

Comment: So I mapped $[1 => 17.2, 2 => 11, 3 => 128, 4 => 1, 5 => 1200, 6 => 38.7]$ and the expected value is $232.65$. I rolled a dice $20$ times and got the following sequence: $[3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 6, 2, 5, 4, 6, 1, 3, 1, 2]$. Summing the values gives: $4299$ and dividing by $20$ gives $214.95$ which is close and I guess would get closer with more throws. So basically the expected value is a way to estimate the running average of a long sequence of occurrences? Have I got it right?

Comment: @Jim, Yes, I believe you do. If you don't program it is worthwhile to learn a language like Python so you can simulate these experiments with bigger data sets.

Comment: So I did try that and the results are: $227.28$ for $1000$ "throws", $227.334$ for $10000$, $232.634$ for $100000$, $232.985$ for $1000000$, $232.865$ for $10,000,000$, $232.6584$ for $100000000$ and $232.639$ for $1000000000$. So it is a range between of outcomes and the expected value $232.65$ is somewhere between the range. To be honest I was expecting that after $100000$ it would stabilize at the $232.65$. How come it fluctuates still?

Comment: @Jim Random number generators are not truly random and even if they were there is always uncertainty. You can try calling the seed function between each iteration to see if your values are tighter. Remember also, in a random process like throwing a die it is possible to throw a million sixes in a row. It is not likely but if you could toss a die once every second for eternity that would happen. In fact, you would get unimaginably long streaks.

Comment: I have one last question, probably sounds trivia, but I like to make sure I don't miss anything. The expected value for the dice is generally an example of the process right? Is there any importance knowing that the expected value of a dice is approx. $3.5$ besides the fact that it proves that the dice under test is fair? I mean I can't think of any other usefulness of literary calculating the expected value for dice throws, am I missing something?

Comment: @Jim For dice, I am not sure but if you Google applications of expected value, I am sure you will find many examples. It is also a basic concept in probability theory so if you continue your studies your intuition and insight will increase.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to help me out and answering my questions! I highly appreciate it fwiw. You have helped me a lot to understand the concept

Comment: You are welcome and I can assure you that the majority of the members of this site are willing to spend the time with someone like you who truly wants to learn and is not just looking for someone to do his homework.